# Adding call back from addTarget action function in Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, callback, uirefreshcontrol

I have written category for UITableView class. In that, I have added the method to add the refresh controller.

I want my refresh controller target method to give a callback to the main function.

> My tableView Category .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void (^UITableViewRefreshControllerCompletion) (UITableView *tableView);

@interface UITableView (UITableView)

-(void)addRefreshController:(UITableViewRefreshControllerCompletion)completionblock;
-(void)removeRefreshController;

@end
```

> My tableView Category .m :

```
#import "UITableView+UITableView.h"

@implementation UITableView (UITableView)

-(void)addRefreshController:(UITableViewRefreshControllerCompletion)completionblock {

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    [refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor appthemeblueColor]];
    [self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];

    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

-(void) refreshTableView:(UIRefreshControl* )refreshControl {

     completionblock(self); // I want this to call when this method is getting called
}



-(void)removeRefreshController {

    if([self.refreshControl isRefreshing])
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

> **I am giving call to the refresh controller in my ViewController as:**

```
 [self.profileDetailsrTableView addRefreshController:^(UITableView *tableView){

        [self profileDetailsAPICall];
    }];
```

Comment: Categories cannot add stored properties, so there is no way you can store the block in order to invoke it later.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what you're asking. If you want to be able to call the `completionBlock` from inside `refreshTableView`, you need to store a reference to the callback. You cannot do this in a category because categories cannot contain instance variables.

Comment: can I store completionBlock  inside the refresh control object?

Comment: You can subclass `UITableView` to achieve this.

Comment: Instead, If I create the subclass of refreshcontrol and store completionblock in that?

Comment: You may have issues referencing your custom refresh control in the category. You're going to have to do some casting and type checking. It's not impossible, but I'd say it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by taking subclass of UIRefreshControl and stored the completion block;

SubClass-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void (^UITableViewRefreshControllerCompletion) (UITableView *tableView);

@interface UIRefreshControlSubClass : UIRefreshControl

@property(strong, nonatomic) UITableViewRefreshControllerCompletion completionBlock;

@end
```

So the call became:

```
-(void)addRefreshController:(UITableViewRefreshControllerCompletion)completionblock {

    UIRefreshControlSubClass *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControlSubClass alloc]init];
    [refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor appthemeblueColor]];
    [self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
    refreshControl.completionBlock = completionblock;

    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

-(void) refreshTableView:(UIRefreshControlSubClass* )refreshControl {

     refreshControl.completionBlock(self);
}
```